# Xen Server: Missing Physical CPU

Tags: virtualization, xen

One of our Xen server is built on HP blade. Which is having 2 Quad core Physical CPU.

On the Xen it is showing only one CPU, it should show 8 CPUs.

```
processor    : 0
vendor_id    : GenuineIntel
cpu family    : 6
model        : 23
model name    : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5420  @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 6
cpu MHz        : 2500.100
cache size    : 6144 KB
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug        : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu        : yes
fpu_exception    : yes
cpuid level    : 10
wp        : yes
flags        : fpu de tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr mca cmov pat
clflush acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht nx constant_tsc up pni vmx est
ssse3 sse4_1
bogomips    : 5037.75
clflush size    : 64
power management:
```

From the xen side also it is showing only 1 one CPU.

```
cpu_count                : 1
                     vendor: GenuineIntel
                      speed: 2500.100
                  modelname: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5420  @ 2.50GHz
                     family: 6
                      model: 23
                   stepping: 6
                      flags: fpu de tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr mca
cmov pat clflush acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht nx constant_tsc up pni vmx
est ssse3 sse4_1
                   features: 000ce3bd-bfebfbff-00000001-20100800
      features_after_reboot: 000ce3bd-bfebfbff-00000001-20100800
          physical_features: 000ce3bd-bfebfbff-00000001-20100800
                   maskable: base
```

Aybody knows what can be the issue??

Regards,
Pankaj Pal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is VT / Virtualization technology turned on in your motherboard's BIOS? What about the Xen config? That is the first thing that comes to mind.

Also, check that the host operating system was not set up with only 1 CPU, and that SMP / multiprocessing is enabled.

Comment: Its hard to get downtime. I cant chek the bios setting.

Whatever be the VT setting on bios. But it should show 8 CPUs on /proc/cpuinfo.

Comment: Won't show that if disabled in the BIOS. Can't tell you how many motherboards / computers come with VT disabled by default.

Comment: We have other Xen servers in our environment. They are behaving normally.

Comment: Are those other Xen servers running on the same physical hardware as this one? If not, I maintain that you need to check this physical server's BIOS or Operating System settings to see if they are set correctly.